# Char error reading string from text file into a vector array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

Hi all i have a file i'm trying to read into a vector array.
I've checked a few other post that got me as far as i did.
I keep running into an error where it's not allowing me to insert my string using the put_back() function. I keep getting a char error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using namespace std;
string outPutFileName;
vector<vector<string> > array2D;
#define HEIGHT 32
#define WIDTH 9

int main() {
string x;
string line;
string filename;
ifstream infile;


infile.open("file.txt");


if (infile.fail()) {
    cerr << " The file you are trying to access cannot be found or opened";
    exit(1);
}

array2D.resize(HEIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    array2D[i].resize(WIDTH);
}
    while (getline(infile, line)) {
        istringstream streamA(line);

        while (streamA >> x) {
            for (int row = 0; row < HEIGHT; row++) {
                for (int col= 0; col < WIDTH; col++) {
                    array2D[row][col].push_back(x);
                    col++;
                }
                row++;
            }
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <WIDTH; j++) {
            cout << array2D[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `array2D[row][col]` is `std::string`, you are attempting to call `push_back` on that rather than one of the vectors. You probably meant:

```
array2D[row][col] = x;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, when i try that assignment my array gets loaded with zero's?

Comment: The vector will be loaded with whatever the last input from the file is. Your loop logic is probably incorrect, as you are just filling the entire vector with each input.

Comment: Ohh, i was attempting to create a scenario where the rows and columns from the file would be read into my vector? Is the the nature of a vector or just poor programming on my part to read from the last input?

Comment: In that case, read into `x` every loop iteration, rather than reading once before the loop.

Comment: In that case, make a new question with your new issues; my answer should solve the problem which you outlined in this one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help i found a solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using namespace std;
string outPutFileName;
vector<vector<string> > array2D;
#define HEIGHT 32
#define WIDTH 9

int main() {
string x;
string line;
string filename;
ifstream infile;


infile.open("file.txt");

//error check
if (infile.fail()) {
    cerr << " The file you are trying to access cannot be found or opened";
    exit(1);
}
array2D.resize(HEIGHT);
for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    array2D[i].resize(WIDTH);
}
int row;
while (getline(infile, line)) {
    istringstream streamA(line);

    int col = 0;
    while (streamA >> x) {
        array2D[row][col] = x;
        col++; // Note: This might go out of bounds
    }
    row++; // Note: This might go out of bounds
}

    for (int i = 0; i <HEIGHT; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j <WIDTH; j++) {
            cout << array2D[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```